# how to flip google.maps symbol?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a piece of dummy code like this:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922}
  });

  var someIcon = {
    path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: 'gold',
    strokeWeight: 14
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: someIcon,
    map: map
  });
}
```

It contains the icon `someIcon`. Sometimes I need it to be flipped vertically or horizontally. Not just rotated. How do I do that?

In order to illustrate the problem, imagine a bicyclist that travels from the left to the right. Then he decides to travel back and now he rides from the right to the left. His icon must be flipped horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys. In order to complete this task and not to leave the question unanswered I answer to myself. Maybe this will help someone.

There is no way to do such a thing. But you can perform a trick: create a blank `svg` file in a vector graphics editor, save the file. Open the file with a text editor and replace the contents of the `<path>` tag with the string from the `path` property of the icon object in your script. Then open the file again in the graphic editor and flip the image. Save it. Open the file with the text editor and you'll see the `<path>` contents that you need. Use it as the `path` of another image which you'll be using instead of the original image.